# How to open horizontal split that takes full width of the window in vim

Tags: vim

I'm opening a terminal in most of my project. I want to open the terminal in full width when there is already a vertical split in the window. It would be awesome if it can work with `Nerdtree` so it doesn't take space from `Nerdtree`.

```
 +-------------------------+
 |            |            |
 |            |            |
 |            |            |
 +------------+            |
 |            |            |
 |   Actual   |            |
 |            |            |
 +-------------------------+

 +-------------------------+
 |            |            |
 |            |            |
 |            |            |
 +------------+------------|
 |                         |
 |  Expected               |
 |                         |
 +-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way to move the window to very bottom of the screen using `CTRL-W J`

> CTRL-W J  Move the current window to be at the very bottom, using the
> full width of the screen.  This works like closing the current
> window and then creating another one with ":botright split",
> except that the current window contents is used for the new
> window.

Following opens up split view, move it to the very bottom of the screen and set the size to 10 then go to insert mode in the terminal.

```
nnoremap <Leader>th :sp<CR><C-w>J10<C-w>_:terminal<CR>i
```